How do I change the value of a label dynamically depending on a ComboBox in CustomKinter?
This is my first time using CustomKinter to make a simple GUI. I am trying to get the value of a customtkinter label to change depending on the value selected by the combobox. The textvariable for the output should change for the values in the calculate_output function; the output label is not changing.
from tkinter import StringVar

import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Window")
root.geometry("400x300")

label_1 = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Value:", font=("Frutiger", 21))
label_1.place(x=100, y=100)

values = ["80", "150", "180", "250"]

drop_down = ctk.CTkComboBox(root, values=values, border_color="#0072CE", font=("Frutiger", 21),
                            button_color="#005EB8")
drop_down.place(x=220, y=100)

output_var = StringVar()

label_2 = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Output:", font=("Frutiger", 21))
label_2.place(x=100, y=200)

output = ctk.CTkLabel(root, font=("Frutiger", 21), textvariable=output_var)
output.place(x=200, y=200)


def calculate_output(event):
    drop_value = drop_down.get()
    try:
        if drop_value == "80":
            output_var.set("None")
        elif drop_value == "150":
            output_var.set("Aluminium")
        elif drop_value == "180":
            output_var.set("Copper")
        elif drop_value == "250":
            output_var.set("Tin")
    except ValueError:
        output_var.set("Invalid input")


drop_down.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", calculate_output)

root.mainloop()

enter image description here
I tried editting the function and binding but I have no idea where the issue is. Help would be appreciated.

Put a print(repr(drop_value)) in calculate_output(), so that you can tell exactly what is being read from the combobox - maybe the values are ending up as integers?  Note that your except ValueError: block will never be executed, there's nothing in the try block that is likely to cause such an error.

You can use the command parameter of the CTkComboBox to link it to your function as such:
drop_down = ctk.CTkComboBox(root, values=values, border_color="#0072CE", font=("Frutiger", 21), button_color="#005EB8", command=calculate_output)
That way the function will be executed every time you select a new value.
Also make sure to define the function before you link it to the combobox. Your final code would look like this:
from tkinter import StringVar

import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Window")
root.geometry("400x300")

label_1 = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Value:", font=("Frutiger", 21))
label_1.place(x=100, y=100)

values = ["80", "150", "180", "250"]

output_var = StringVar()

label_2 = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Output:", font=("Frutiger", 21))
label_2.place(x=100, y=200)

output = ctk.CTkLabel(root, font=("Frutiger", 21), textvariable=output_var)
output.place(x=200, y=200)


def calculate_output(event):
    drop_value = drop_down.get()
    try:
        if drop_value == "80":
            output_var.set("None")
        elif drop_value == "150":
            output_var.set("Aluminium")
        elif drop_value == "180":
            output_var.set("Copper")
        elif drop_value == "250":
            output_var.set("Tin")
    except ValueError:
        output_var.set("Invalid input")

drop_down = ctk.CTkComboBox(root, values=values, border_color="#0072CE", font=("Frutiger", 21),
                            button_color="#005EB8", command=calculate_output)
drop_down.place(x=220, y=100)

root.mainloop()


Note that the callback for command option of CTkComboBox expects an argument, the selected value, so it is not necessary to call drop_value = drop_down.get().  Just change the argument event to drop_value.


I am trying to get the value of a customtkinter label to change
depending on the value selected by the combobox. The textvariable for
the output should change for the values in the calculate_output
function the output label is not changing.

The problem can be fixed.
Connecting it to a callback function to print the selected option on click event.
drop_down.configure(command=calculate_output) # <== add this
drop_down.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", calculate_output)

root.mainloop()

Screenshot:

